# How to prevent PhpStorm from reassigning file types?

Tags: phpstorm

I am currently evaluating PhpStorm as an alternative to Aptana Studio, we use right now. But one issue really annoys.

We use the *.tpl file extension for our PHP templates. This file type is usually mapped to Smarty. It was quite easy to set this to "PHP files (PHP)". But each time I restart PhpStorm, I get this message:

```
File type recognized: File extension *.tpl was reassigned to Smarty
```

So it maps the file type back to Smarty. If I try to "Revert" it through the "Event log", it will than map it to "Text files" but not back to PHP.

So, how can I prevent PhpStrom from touching my manual changes are keep the mapping to PHP (and not to Smarty)?

Comment: PhpStorm version/build used (Help | About)?

Comment: The most current Verion 7.1.3, Build #PS-133.982

Comment: Strange: I've just checked this in 7.1.3 as well as v8 EAP -- all work fine when re-assigning `*.tpl` from Smarty to `PHP files (PHP)` -- I've restarted few times but no message about automatic reassignment has appeared (and I do know what you mean by that -- have seen it in v6 with `.htaccess` files). Can you attach your idea.log file?

Comment: OK, it seems like using "Revert" once and than changing the settings after that will fix the issue. But only until you revert them back to the original settings. So this issue might be fixed, but it really isn't a good solution.

Comment: btw: the idea.log had no entry about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the following method would work:

**Without touching the configuration:**

1. Change the file type mapping through the `Preferences > Editor > File Types` setting
2. Restart PhpStorm
3. As soon as the "File type recognized" message appears, click the "Revert" links (see question)
4. Redo step 1

Now PhpStorm should not map it back again.

**With touching the configuration files:**

In your user profile, you should have a folder `.WebIde70/config/options` (or something similar) and there you should have a file called `filetypes.xml` (if not create an empty one), where you can set the mapping and prevent PhpStorm from reverting it. Here is a simple example with only the mapping for my question:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application>
  <component name="FileTypeManager" version="11">
    <ignoreFiles list="CVS;SCCS;RCS;rcs;.DS_Store;.svn;.pyc;.pyo;*.pyc;*.pyo;.git;*.hprof;_svn;.hg;*.lib;*~;__pycache__;.bundle;*.rbc;" />
    <extensionMap>
      <mapping ext="tpl" type="PHP" />
      <removed_mapping ext="tpl" approved="true" type="Smarty" />
    </extensionMap>
  </component>
</application>
```

As you can see, the settings file not only sets the new mapping, but also removes the original mapping for the Smarty template.